# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES to localhost

Tags: mysql

I try to grant permission to all users. When I do the next:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'my' IDENTIFIED BY 'er';
```

and than try to entet mysql from this ip and with the pasword "er", I see the next massage:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
```

What I do wrong? maybe I need to grant permission to all user in the organization?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' while attempting to grant privileges. How do I grant privileges?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484722/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-while-attempting-to-grant-privileges)

Answer (score 0):

Your granting to root@my you probably should be granting to root@localhost