# ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Why oh why can I not connect to mysql?

```
mysql -u root -ptest101 -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

In my.cnf I have the below

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
```

I also ran the below...

```
'UPDATE mysql.user SET Password = PASSWORD('test101') WHERE User = 'root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I can access on the host machine using mysql -u root -ptest101 but not using mysql -u root -ptest101 -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Wow...why is this happening?  I am n ubuntj 12.04

```
mysql> SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'root';
+---------------------------------------------+
| host                                        |
+---------------------------------------------+
| %                                           |
| 127.0.0.1                                   |
| ::1                                         | |
| localhost                                   |
+---------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Remember that mysql accounts aren't just usernames. they're `user@host` pairs, where either of the pair can be a wildcard. You might be using the right username, but did you grant the right host privileges as well?

Answer (score 419, accepted):

Your `root` account, and this statement applies to any account, may only have been added with localhost access (which is recommended).

You can check this with:

```
SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'root';
```

If you only see results with `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`, you cannot connect from an external source. If you see other IP addresses, but not the one you're connecting from - that's also an indication.

You will need to add the IP address of each system that you want to grant access to, and then grant privileges:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'ip_address' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'ip_address';
```

If you see `%`, well then, there's another problem altogether as that is "any remote source". If however you do want any/all systems to connect via root, use the `%` wildcard to grant access:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
```

Finally, reload the permissions, and you should be able to have remote access:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: I did what was suggested.  See that outuo above.  I still get same error.  I cant connect.

Comment: This post worked http://bucktownbell.com/?p=653

Comment: That sql statement "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'" need a ";" after it....

Comment: and now it just complains that `Access denied for user`

Comment: and after this you should do `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'%' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');` mysql docs only say to update `'root'@'localhost'` to "change the root password" which deceives people into believing they have changed the root password when they haven't.

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';  Is wrong, replace the % with *

Comment: @JazzCat `%` is correct as documented at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/request-access.html

Comment: If you get access denied for user look here.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16004129/4301119

Comment: This comment worked. I also had the problem where my root user was not having rights to connect from any host or my specific host. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for mysql 8 as well

Comment: Change the bind address to 0.0.0.0 and followed by
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
worked like magic. I'm running two ec2 instances incase if anyone runs into trouble with that and remember to run with public IP. You can use nmap to confirm ports are exposed to outside world, just to be on the safer side.

Comment: Why is this much hard? Do I need to add hosts for all users one by one?

Comment: this works for me using Docker-Compose with mysql:8.0.32 & phpmyadmin:latest with this command `CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';`. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 31):

Following two steps worked perfectly fine for me:

1. Comment out the bind address from the file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

   `#bind-address  = 127.0.0.1`
2. Run following query in phpMyAdmin:

   `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: + `sudo service mysql restart`

Comment: Removing the bind will make the server open on ALL IP's... this is a security issue!

Comment: Works for me. Thanks man.

Comment: @AlexFrenkel But dont we have password authentication via privileges? How can you otherwise access it from a dynamic ip for debugging purpose. I can change it later for production

Comment: On mysql 8+, you need to create the user instead of implicitly creating the user with the grant statement. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50197630/14068350

Answer (score 23):

Open MySQL via terminal

```
mysql -u root --host=127.0.0.1 -p
```

Choose Database

```
mysql>use mysql
```

Grant Access

```
mysql>GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'redhat@123';
```

Refresh Rights

```
mysql>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Checking Status of user

```
mysql> SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'root';
```

Comment: sudo service mysql restart
need to run after this 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

> mysql> CREATE USER 'name'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passWord'; Query OK, 0
>   rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'name'@'%'; Query OK, 0 rows
>   affected (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES; Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql>

1. Make sure you have your name and % the right way round
2. Makes sure you have added your port 3306 to any firewall you may be running (although this will give a different error message)

hope this helps someone...

Answer (score -1):

For those who are able to access cpanel, there is a simpler way getting around it.

1. log in cpanel => "Remote MySQL" under DATABASES section:
2. Add the IPs / hostname which you are accessing from
3. done!!!

Answer (score -7):

Go to PhpMyAdmin, click on desired database,
go to Privilages tab and create new user "remote", and give him all privilages
and in host field set "Any host" option(%).

Answer (score -13):

there an easy way to fix this error

just replace the files on the folder : `C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql`

with the files on : `C:\xampp\mysql\backup\mysql`