# mysql fails to allow remote connection

Tags: mysql

I have followed the steps here:

[ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101243/error-1130-hy000-host-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

Carried out this activity dozens of times and it worked -- now for some reason it is not

I have done:

1. Comment out bind-address in my.cnf and restart service
2. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
3. FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

The only difference here is that MySQL is running in a VM under VirtualBox and I am connecting to the VM mysql instance via WIndows 7.

SSH and other services work fine...

The passwords are fine as they work when I connect via SSH...

My new modem/router possibly at fault, blocking outgoing or ingoing connections on port 3306???

I assume that traffic from a host to guest still goes through the router...but the thing is...my requests are certainly making to the MySQL server as the log file shows fail requests...

WTF amm I missing???

The error I receive: Error No. 1045
Access denied for user 'root'@'my-desktop' (Using Passowrd: YES)

Answer (score 1):

You also have to edit my.cnf. Change:

```
bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

then restart mysql. Also, if you are going to allow outside access, create a user other than root. That's always a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

By default connection from outside are not allowed for security reasons.

Because exposing your database to the public internet is never a good idea, you will need to whitelist the IP address manually to allow connection.

Comment: no in sql remote management you can allow ipadress to access the db from outside

Comment: the % is a wild card in the grant command... can you clarify...example?

Comment: @Alex.Barylski what are you using to run mysql ? xampp?

Comment: I have debian installed as a guest vm under windows...so its remote

Comment: something is clearly denying user, check in the log it will be more verbose `tail -f /var/log/mysql.log`

Comment: I did that...the output is the last sentance of my OP is that exactly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62937/discussion-between-meda-and-alex-barylski).