# AWS EC2 mysql root password issue

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Installed the below in amazon ec2 new instance.
yum install -y httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php56-mysqlnd

Then did a start of mysqld using service mysqld start .   It gave a list of commands that needs  to be executed.

Followed the instructions in the service output to change the root password.  When the below command is run it gives an error

```
/usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqladmin: connect to server at '177.37.1.30' failed
error: 'Host 'ip-177-37-1-30.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server'
```

How do I fix this?

```
service mysqld start
Initializing MySQL database:  Installing MySQL system tables...
161102  4:22:07 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.52) starting as process 3137 ...
OK

Filling help tables...
161102  4:22:07 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.52) starting as process 3144 ...
OK

To start mysqld at boot time you have to copy
support-files/mysql.server to the right place for your system

PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MySQL root USER !
To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:

/usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'
/usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqladmin -u root -h ip-177-37-1-30 password 'new-password'

Alternatively you can run:
/usr/libexec/mysql55/mysql_secure_installation

which will also give you the option of removing the test
databases and anonymous user created by default.  This is
strongly recommended for production servers.

See the manual for more instructions.

You can start the MySQL daemon with:
cd /usr ; /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld_safe &

You can test the MySQL daemon with mysql-test-run.pl
cd /usr/mysql-test ; perl mysql-test-run.pl

Please report any problems at http://bugs.mysql.com/
```

Comment: Please have a look a this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101243/error-1130-hy000-host-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server) , hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Give Nat permissions in VPC where instance is running. 
thank you.