# Can I connect to mysql server with only mysql client installed?

Tags: mysql

This is very novice question I am very new to working with Databases, primarily an user of R, also comfortable Bash Unix Shell.  I have a MySQL server 5.7 installed on windows 10 laptop and have been using Workbench for accessing or populating databases.

I want to have a good command of in-database analytics and had a few broad questions.

Its easy to access MySQL database on my laptop from R on my laptop that was simple.  Also if I go to windows command line and type `mysql -u -root -p` from the directory `MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/bin` in can start typing SQL commands at mysql prompt.

My question is, regarding accessing my MySQL databases in my laptop or any other mysql server.  From a remote Linux session on a VM, or after starting R in that Linux session.  I linux can I install a mysql client alone on a Linux VM and access MySQL databases or do I have to install MySQL server as well.

My premonition was that I wouldn't have to install the server but I was experimenting in Windows Linux Subsystem(WLS) (which is a source of confusion itself since  WLS is a new thing and I didn't want to generalize what I learn from experimenting in WLS to working from a remote Linux machine.

Then there is another question of working off a Linux in Virtual Box installed on my windows.

To simplify my question I would like at least know be certain about does one need to install mysql server to and have it running to access any mysql database on another machine or will it suffice to have a mysql client installed?

Your input will be greatly appreciated, as I have been only successful in trying to use my WLS and read several post/blogs I would like to be clear about how MySQL works before continuing my experiments.

Ideally I would like to query data from any bash shell that I can find or any R session.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not need to install mysql server on a computer to be able to access another mysql server remotely. The client will suffice.

Comment: Thanks that narrows down all the possible solutions that I image ( I get a sense of what is happening by practicing and it give rise to all possible scenarios that I can imagine).

Comment: And as for Windows Linux subsystem, I was able to get mysql client to work by making sure I am in the right directory and after granting the wildcard (%) IP addr as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101243/error-1130-hy000-host-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)