# Host '19x.xxx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Tags: database, database-connection, mariadb

I am trying to add a database on "https://17x.xxx.xxx.xxx/phpmyadmin/" as my database for my Django project. I have given correct database name, username and password. But I get this error.

After deep investigation I found out that I cant access my database even from the command line or any other external source beside phpmyadmin site

The error that I get is,

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1130, "Host '19x.xxx.xxx.xxx' is
>   not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server")

I haven't done this before. The database server is not mine. Is there something wrong with the way I've proceeded?

Comment: Which database are you trying to connect? MariaDB or MySql

Comment: As for the error I think it is MariaDB

Comment: Server type: MariaDB

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database via phpmyadmin / command line

Comment: The error definitely comes from the DB server. There seems to be a restriction of source addresses your user can connect from. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server) as well

Comment: @NiranjRajasekaran I haven't tried to connect with the command line, but yes with phpmyadmin i have connected

Comment: As @shmee said there could be restrictions on how many connections is allowed to connect at a time, so try to disconnect from your phpmyadmin and try it once again from django

Comment: I tried using the command line.. the same error appears

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101243/error-1130-hy000-host-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server

Comment: If you can use PHPMyAdmin you could use that to grant `%` to the user. This should allow that user to connect remotely. You also will need to allow remote connections but this depends how its setup. Are you running this on a server using cPanel or something else? This is probably not a Django issue.

Comment: @PabasaraRanathunga but connecting via phpmyadmin is not the same as connecting using Django's backend driver. With phpmyadmin, the connection will be made from the server that runs the phpmyadmin page, very likely this is also the server that the DB runs on. If your user was created using `'user'@'localhost'` phpmyadmin will work perfectly while connection attempts form any other source IP will be rejected. You'll need to get that info from an admin on the DB

Comment: well I tried what was suggested by @shmee and shlomta1 but I still get that error.

Comment: @SamCollins I tried that but no use. yup it seems that this is not a Django issue since the same error occur in the command line. Could you please suggest an edit for my question as this no longer is a Django issue. thanks

Comment: @PabasaraRanathunga I could but then your question would basically be a duplicate of the ones suggested by other users. Without details about how your database server is setup you might not be able to get much more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after several tries I found what was wrong. The problem was that **there was no user in the db server for my local IP [private IP]**.
So I **added a new user** to phpmyadmin with required privileges and tried again and it worked.

```
mysql -u {user_name} -p{password} -h {db_host} {db_name}
```

and I got

> Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
>   Your MySQL connection id is xxxxxx
>   Server version: 5.5.5-10.1.31-MariaDB MariaDB Serverckquote