# How do I fix root account getting "ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host ... is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server"

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb

I have always had a dev mysql server where my code worked with the account

`root@'localhost'/(no password)`

with full global privileges.

All I did recently was to set the privileges to additionally allow

`root@'%'/(no passsword)`

same full privileges so I could access comfortably from navicat on my ipad on same LAN.

Everything worked fine until I had reason to restart the xampp mysql server and bingo: I get this error wherever I'm trying to access from. I've googled and most resolutions suggest first accessing through phpmyadmin or something like

`mysql -u root --host=127.0.0.1 -p`

from command prompt but these all give the same error.

What can I do to fix?

Comment: Looks Like a Duplicate of this [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101243/error-1130-hy000-host-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)