# mysql_upgrade - FATAL ERROR: Upgrade Failed

Tags: mysql

I recently had my MySQL server upgraded from 5.1 to 5.5 and I'm trying to upgrade my databases using mysql_upgrade but I keep getting this error:

```
[root@ip-??-???-???-??? ~]# mysql_upgrade -uadmin -p
Enter password:
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

I can't figure why this won't run. MySQL Server is running.

Comment: Try adding --verbose to the mysql_upgrade and see if that shows anything. Try doing this while the server is not running and see if that makes a difference. Related thread on sf: http://serverfault.com/questions/527422/mysql-upgrade-is-failing-with-no-real-reason-given

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue going from MySQL 5.5 to 5.6 on OS X (installed via MacPorts).

Seems that `mysql_upgrade` needs to be run as user `root` and only `root` and a password needs to be set up for the user. Any other user with administrative privileges does not seem work.

So the only valid command seems to be: `mysql_upgrade -u root -p`

Initial solution by [Chris_H at FreeBSD forums](https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?t=40884).

Comment: In fact, it works with other user with sufficients privileges, but you have to let the password empty. You'll have a prompt to type it after command execution.

Comment: @Groco - yes, `-p` implies the password prompt. So yes, might work with other administrator accounts as well provided that the password is not supplied as an argument of the execution.

Answer (score 8):

Worked for me, but I had to use this:

```
mysql_upgrade --port=3306 --user=root --password=PASSWORD
```

I work on

```
mysql -V
```

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

Answer (score 3):

For my case, I need to pass my socket file location explicitly.

```
mysql_upgrade -S /usr/local/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 2):

If you run MySQL on a non-standard port be sure to include --port=xxxxxx

I found that skipping that can cause the error you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

The FATAL ERROR is solved:

1º - Execute shell command: `service mysqld stop`

2º - Then, rename `/etc/my.cnf` to `/etc/my.cnfbkp`

3º - Execute shell command: `service mysqld start`

4º - Execute shell command: `mysql_upgrade -u root -p YOUR_ROOT_PASSWORD`

5º - Rename `/etc/my.cnfbkp` to `/etc/my.cnf`

6º - Execute shell command: `service mysqld restart`

Answer (score 0):

My installation on Windows server requires port and user/pass specification.

```
--port=3306 --user=root --password=XXXX
```

Comment: Not sure why my comment was edited, you have to define the password after the --password switch.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the configuration line to your my.cnf
At the end add

[mysqlcheck]
socket = /dbabcstorage/data/mysql5/mysql.sock

the correct value you can copy in the previous lines of my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on a CentOS/Plesk server:

mysql_upgrade -uadmin -p`< /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` -f

service mysqld restart

http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/427

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

Follow the steps as **ADMINISTRATOR** account:

1) Install MySQL

2) In the my.ini file, located on the MySQL path, set datadir e basedir

**3)** **Move ALL THE CONTENT** of "%MySQL%/Data" folder to the datadir above

4) Run the upgrade:

```
mysql_upgrade
```

5) Create Windows Service like this:

```
sc create MySQL binPath=C:/MySQL
```

To remove the Windows Service:

```
sc delete MySQL
```