# MAMP mysql update fails

Tags: mamp

When I try to start my mysql and apache servers through MAMP on macOS, I get a message every time saying that mysql needs to be updated.

I try to update mysql through the MAMP interface, but it errors out with this:

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Looking for 'mysql' as: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqlcheck
Error: Failed while fetching Server version! Could be due to unauthorized access.
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

How do I fix this so that I can start my servers properly?

EDIT for clarity: I appreciate the link to the other thread. Very similar but I still need help with getting MAMP to update mysql. When I try /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_upgrade --port=3306 -u root -p in the terminal as suggested in that post I get:

```
Looking for 'mysql' as: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck' with connection arguments: '--port=3306'
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Running 'mysqlcheck' with connection arguments: '--port=3306'
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
mysql.db                                           OK
mysql.event                                        OK
mysql.func                                         OK
mysql.general_log                                  OK
mysql.help_category                                OK
mysql.help_keyword                                 OK
mysql.help_relation                                OK
mysql.help_topic                                   OK
mysql.innodb_index_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.innodb_table_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.ndb_binlog_index                             OK
mysql.plugin                                       OK
mysql.proc                                         OK
mysql.procs_priv                                   OK
mysql.proxies_priv                                 OK
mysql.servers                                      OK
mysql.slave_master_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_relay_log_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_worker_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_worker_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slow_log                                     OK
mysql.tables_priv                                  OK
mysql.time_zone                                    OK
mysql.time_zone_leap_second                        OK
mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
mysql.user                                         OK

Repairing tables
mysql.innodb_index_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.innodb_table_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_master_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_relay_log_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_worker_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_worker_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'...
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 62: Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 63: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 64: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 66: Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 67: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 68: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 81: Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 82: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 83: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 110: Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 111: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 112: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 128: Table 'mysql.slave_worker_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 129: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 130: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1896: Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1897: Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1898: Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1899: Table 'mysql.slave_worker_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1900: Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1904: Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1908: Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

I also tried finding the my.cnf file for MAMP and backing it up as someone else in the other thread suggested but could not find it. If someone would not mind pointing out to me where it is, so that I can see if updating mysql after that works.

I will also add that I am using MAMP version 4.2 on macOS 10.12. If that helps any.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_upgrade - FATAL ERROR: Upgrade Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564509/mysql-upgrade-fatal-error-upgrade-failed)

Comment: @PascalMeunier Thank you for the link, I appreciate it, but still need help. I tried some of the things in that article but they did not seem to help. I have updated my original post with some of the things I have found.