# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) after new installation on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Today I did a login as root into Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS ll

and then `apt-get install mariadb-server` (without sudo but as root).

With `mySQL -h localhost -u root --password=<PW>` I got

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

With `mySQL -u root -p` I logged into the DB and did

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<PW>';
FLUSH ALL PRIVILEGES;
```

But this did not help. Have you got any idea?
I did not find the answer for the similar questions.

Comment: Have you tried reseting the password for root?

Answer (score 371):

**TL;DR:** To access newer versions of mysql/mariadb as the root user, after a new install, you need to be in a root shell (ie `sudo mysql -u root`, or `mysql -u root` inside a shell started by `su -` or `sudo -i` first)

---

Having just done the same upgrade, on Ubuntu, I had the same issue.

What was odd was that

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

Would accept my password, and allow me to set it, but  I couldn't log in as `root` via the `mysql` client

I had to start mariadb with

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

to get access as root, whilst all the other users could still access fine.

Looking at the `mysql.user` table I noticed for root the `plugin` column is set to `unix_socket` whereas all other users it is set to 'mysql_native_password'. A quick look at this page: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/unix_socket-authentication-plugin/ explains that the Unix Socket enables logging in by matching `uid` of the process running the client with that of the user in the `mysql.user` table. In other words to access mariadb as `root` you have to be logged in as root.

Sure enough restarting my mariadb daemon with authentication required I can login as root with

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

or

```
sudo su -
mysql -u root -p
```

Having done this I thought about how to access without having to do the sudo, which is just a matter of running these mysql queries

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

(replacing `<password>` with your desired mysql root password). This enabled password logins for the root user.

Alternatively running the mysql query:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE user = 'root' AND plugin = 'unix_socket';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Will change the root account to use password login without changing the password, but this may leave you with a mysql/mariadb install with no root password on it.

After either of these you need to restarting mysql/mariadb:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

And voila I had access from my personal account via `mysql -u root -p`

**PLEASE NOTE THAT DOING THIS IS REDUCING SECURITY** Presumably the MariaDB developers have opted to have root access work like this for a good reason.

Thinking about it I'm quite happy to have to `sudo mysql -u root -p` so I'm switching back to that, but I thought I'd post my solution as I couldn't find one elsewhere.

Comment: btw, if you're lazy like me, you can save like two seconds with `sudo service mysql restart`

Comment: Does `<password>` mean "type in an arbitrary password", "type in the password for the root user on your machine", or "literally type in the string <password>"?

Comment: <password> in the grant statement means 'provide a password that you want the mysql root user to use to login'. It should be different from the host system's root user password for security reasons - though there is no technical reason you can't use the same password.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, great for dev but how do you reverse this back to original ?

Comment: @sam : To revert changing security just change the plugin back to 'unix_socket': `UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'unix_socket' WHERE user = 'root' AND plugin = 'mysql_native_password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: For anyone who is wondering, MariaDB made this change in 10.4.3, where unix_socket is now the default for root@localhost: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/ .

Comment: I used `sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables` instead of `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`, and it works.

Comment: At some mariadb versions it's need to be first `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` before any action to `GRANT`etc. could be taken. At create new user please follow this instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555328/error-1396-hy000-operation-create-user-failed-for-jacklocalhost

Answer (score 43):

In clean Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, MariaDB *root* login for *localhost* changed from password style to sudo login style...

so, just do

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

since we want to login with password, create another user 'user'

in MariaDB console... (you get in MariaDB console with 'sudo mysql -u root')

```
use mysql
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';
\q
```

then in bash shell prompt,

```
mysql-workbench
```

and you can login with 'user' with 'yourpassword' on localhost

Comment: Nope. `sudo mysql -u root` gives me the same error.

Answer (score 27):

from superuser [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/questions/957708/mysql-mariadb-error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost):

```
sudo mysql -u root
use mysql;
update user set plugin='' where User='root';
flush privileges;
exit;
```

Comment: Nope. sudo mysql -u root gives me the same error.

Comment: this works for me on mariadb 10.3.34 with ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 20):

Try the command

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

press enter and assign a new password for *root* in **mysql/mariadb**.

If you get an error like

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

enable the service with

```
service mysql start
```

now if you re-enter with

```
mysql -u root -p
```

if you follow the problem enter with `sudo su` and `mysql -u root -p` now apply permissions to *root*

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';`

this fixed my problem in **MariaDB**.

Good luck

Answer (score 4):

I had to be logged into Ubuntu as root in order to access Mariadb as root.  It may have something to do with that "Harden ..." that it prompts you to do when you first install.  So:

```
$ sudo su
[sudo] password for user: yourubunturootpassword
# mysql -r root -p
Enter password: yourmariadbrootpassword
```

and you're in.

Answer (score 3):

The new command to flush the privileges is:

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES`

The old command `FLUSH ALL PRIVILEGES` does not work any more.

You will get an error that looks like that:

`MariaDB [(none)]> FLUSH ALL PRIVILEGES;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALL PRIVILEGES' at line 1`

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Run mysql_upgrade.

Check that

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
```

says

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ... WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Check that the table exists _mysql.proxies_priv_.

[Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' while attempting to grant privileges. How do I grant privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484722/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-while-attempting-to-grant-privileges)

Answer (score 0):

System like Ubuntu prefers to use **auth_socket** plugin. It will try to authenticate by comparing your username in DB and process which makes mysql request; it is described in [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.5/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html)

> The socket plugin checks whether the socket user name (the operating
>   system user name) matches the MySQL user name specified by the client
>   program to the server, and permits the connection only if the names
>   match.

Instead you may want to back with the **mysql_native_password**, which will require user/password to authenticate.

About the method to achieve that, I recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42742610/9042200) instead.

Answer (score -1):

First of all close terminal to exit this cmd;

Then run: `sudo mysql` (Do not forgot `sudo` otherwise MySQL requires password which you don't know - use `sudo` to skip mysql password authentication)

Select `mysql` database by following cmd

```
mysql> use mysql
```

then set new password for your root user

```
mysql> alter user root@localhost identified with mysql_native_password by 'MyNewPassword@123';
```

then

```
mysql> flush privileges;
```

and `quit` to close mysql connection

```
mysql> quit
```

Now you can run `sudo mysql_secure_installation` without any error
Here you have to enter your new set password (MyNewPassword@123)

Comment: When I run "use mysql" then I get this error Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'