# MariaDB setup for Confluence "Access denied for user"

Tags: jdbc, datasource, confluence

I have a problem. I try configure Confluence, but I don't know what do in step "Configure Database". I use Instruction https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-a-mysql-datasource-in-apache-tomcat-1867.html 
Description of installation:

-CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406

-confluence 5.9.8

-Server version: 5.5.47-MariaDB MariaDB Server

-mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar

1 way:

---Datasource setup steps and error:

1. Select "MySQL External Database"
2. Select "Connect via a Datasource"
3. Enter datasource name (java:comp/env/jdbc/confluence or jdbc/confluence) and click "Next"
4. Receive the following error: "Could not lookup datasource successfully: com.atlassian.config.bootstrap.BootstrapException: Could not locate datasource: jdbc/confluence"

[enter image description here][1]
2 way:

1. Select "MySQL External Database"

   2. Select "Direct JDBC Connection"
   3. Enter

Driver Class Name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Database URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/confluence?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8 User Name = confluence

and click "Next"

4. Receive the following error:

"The following error(s) occurred:  •configuring.db.failed •java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'confluence'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

[enter image description here][2]

BUT:

MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for 'confluence'@'localhost'; +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | Grants for confluence@localhost                                                                                  | +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'confluence'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*6498EC8B7A8C0138E99B1203CED08CF40ACF04B0' | | GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `confluence`.* TO 'confluence'@'localhost'                                                | +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 2 rows in set (0.04 sec)

Help please!

Comment: I'm not an expert, but did you try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068155/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-after-new-instal

Comment: This may or may not be related to your issue, but be aware that MariaDB is not supported on Atlassian Confluence at this time. https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/supported-platforms-207488198.html

Answer (score 0):

Before you can install Confluence, you will have to install a supported database first.

Although MariaDB is related to MySQL it is not supported by Confluence. There is [this feature request](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-29060) to add support for it some day. You can check the [supported platforms](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/supported-platforms-207488198.html) documentation for a valid database.

If you want to go with MySQL then first look up how to install the proper MySQL version on your server and then you can walk through the Confluence [Database Setup](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/database-setup-for-mysql-128747.html) documentation.

If you're not sure what a "Data Source" is, then don't worry about it, but just go with the "Direct JDBC Connection" setup, it's easier.

Answer (score -2):

Install pocket query for confluence
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211199/pocketquery-for-confluence
Download the driver [https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/][1]
and add to WEB-INF/lib folder of confluence

You should be able to connect Database using JDBC option and server jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb and user name and password.

Comment: unrelated answer as this doesn't answer the question. please use comments to give suggestions.