# Fresh mysql-server installation does not ask for password

Tags: mysql, installation, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am installing the package mysql-server on debian (actually Raspbian, the Debian version for raspberry pi). I'm installing it with the following command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

During the installation **I'm not asked to enter a root password**. And if I try to connect to mysql with the following command :

```
mysql -u root
```

or

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and using the system root password, I got the following error :

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I am quite confused since apparently **I should be asked to provide a root password during the installation**.

What should I do ?

Regards.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this:

After installation, run MySql Secure Installation:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

You'll be asked a series of security related configuration questions, including setting the root password.

Once the root password is set, you'll need to be logged in as root (or use `sudo`) to login.  This is a consequence of how MySql uses credentials based on [process uid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068155/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-after-new-instal)

Comment: Thanks! I ran `$ mysql_secure_installation` (i.e. without sudo) and empty password did not work. **Just added** sudo and empty password **worked**! OS: debian-9

Comment: Be aware to not use `\\` chars in your password.

Comment: anyway to set it up to not ask for sudo everytime

Comment: its asking for root password even with sudo on first installation without giving me password.. -_-

Answer (score 25):

**Here you go:**

In the new **my-sql** if the password is left empty while installing then it is based on the `auth_socket` plugin.

The correct way is to login to my-sql with `sudo` privilege.

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p
```

And then updating the password using:

```
$ ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'new-password';
```

Once this is done `stop and start` the mysql server.

```
$  sudo service mysql stop
$  sudo service mysql start
```

For complete details you can refer to [this link](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/).

Do comment for any doubt.

Comment: After reading 5 or so stackoverflow threads regarding this password problem, this was the one that solved the issue. All was missing was the `sudo` before `mysql`.

Comment: Happy to help :) @Pedro

Comment: @Nandesh I was in the same boat as Pedro -- several Stack Overflow and Ask Ubuntu posts, blog posts, etc. tried, all to no avail until I found your simple solution. Well done, and thanks!

Comment: @duckmayr For developer from developers :)

Answer (score 5):

**If someone facing this problem in installing MYSQL in Ubuntu 18.04.**

Ubuntu 18.04 uses sockets for authorization and not passwords!!

(https://websiteforstudents.com/mariadb-installed-without-password-prompts-for-root-on-ubuntu-17-10-18-04-beta/)

For me logging in was as simple as:

```
sudo  mysql -u root
```

Don't forget the `sudo`

I really hope there should have been a message stating that Ubuntu no longer used passwords when attempting to run mysql. this was a really drastic change in functionality.

Answer (score 2):

In my case nothing worked as mentioned here, following worked for me.
As described here also:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html

A superuser account 'root'@'localhost is created. A password for the superuser is set and stored in the error log file. To reveal it, use the following command:

`shell> sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem which prevented me from being able to access mysql all the answers to use `mysql_secure_installation` after running `sudo apt install mysql-server` didn't work. Here's what worked

1. Go to [official mysql installation guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/) and follow line by line
2. You need to download a .deb file from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) that configures which version of mysql you want to install and other configurations
3. After configurations are all done run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mysql-server` This time you'd be asked for a password.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Download apt repository from mysql official site https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

Select your version and click next and select ok and click next.

now

```
sudo apt-get update  

sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

while installing it will ask for password.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the mysql `root` password was my superuser password.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested reading [this question and aswers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895163/how-to-find-out-the-mysql-root-password/27998121#27998121).

Isn't the default password the empty string ?