# Ping-Connection-Pool throws Access Denied to DB although user exist and credentials are OK

Tags: jdbc, mariadb, database-connection, connection-pooling, payara

I'm trying to create a `jdbc-connection-pool` using payara on the console. Using `./asadmin` on `Payara_Server/bin/`

It is Running on Linux and the credentials for the database are `user=jc` and `password=hola123` (dummies), It is for sure this credentials work. I tried them on Mariadb.

I create a connection pool using ./asadmin on Payara, it looks like this:

```
./asadmin create-jdbc-connection-pool --datasourceclassname org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbDataSource 
--restype javax.sql.DataSource --property user=jc:password=hola123:DatabaseName=​cinev2:ServerName=localhost:port=3306 cinePool
```

Now, when I try:

```
./asadmin ping-connection-pool
```

I get an error like this:

```
remote failure: Ping Connection Pool failed for cinePool.
Connection could not be allocated because:
Access denied for user 'jc'@'localhost' to database '​cinev2' Please check the server.log for more details.
Command ping-connection-pool failed.
```

What would be the causes of this Issue other than Credentials? I have checked if the credentials are right and they are, So I've no clue on the issue.

Comment: `Please check the server.log for more details` - Anything helpful in there?

Comment: Is just a log with the past issues. No additional information than what says in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Since it works when locally connecting to the DB it probably really is an access issue.

Please check if you did all steps outlined here: [Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) after new installation on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068155/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-after-new-instal)