# access denied for user ''@'localhost' error in xamp shell

Tags: xampp

I want to create a database in MySQL using command line. so I use shell option in xampp to create it.
I write this line 
create database abc;
access denied for user @'localhost'  to database abc;

Comment: first connect to the mysql database using command "mysql -u username -p password". If it gives access denied , then your credentials are wrong.
Or check this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484722/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-while-attempting-to-grant-privileges that might be related to your issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Comment: @Aparna this first time I am using shell. so should I use my os user and password? or I should create new user and password in shell?

Comment: you just create user first then try to login

Comment: Not OS credentials, you need to enter the mysql username and password which is set while the installation of mysql

Comment: I dont install my sql i am using shell of xampp

Comment: mysql -u root -p     and enter try this  because default in xampp password may be empty

Comment: error 1064 when trying mysql -u root -p