# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using WAMP Server for android registration page development. I am getting this error:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Please help me in fixing this.

Here Is my Config.inc.php file :

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * phpMyAdmin sample configuration, you can use it as base for
 * manual configuration. For easier setup you can use setup/
 *
 * All directives are explained in documentation in the doc/ folder
 * or at <http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/>.
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */

/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'a8b7c6d'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql wampserver';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;



/*
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */

// No warning on  pmadb tables
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;


?>
```

Here is the Config.php file:

```
<?php

/**
 * Database config variables
 */
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "root");
define("DB_DATABASE", "android_api");
?>
```

Here is my exact issue :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ydHA.png)

Comment: you used the wrong password. you specified it as an empty string in the config, but obviously the server doesn't have "no password" on the root account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' while attempting to grant privileges. How do I grant privileges?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484722/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-while-attempting-to-grant-privileges)

Comment: @MarcB if i type any password in that field i can even open the php admin page entire page is getting this error if i do that

Comment: If the `root` user account ___has no password___ then leave the phpMyAdmin `password` field EMPTY. Dont **make up** a password there is no password _currently_

Comment: i just edited my post and added my prblem screenshot plz checkout

Comment: YOu are getting an unknown database error which means you have not yet created the database android_api. Create it through phpmyadmin first.

Comment: SO now you do need to use `phpMyAdmin` to create a database, and one or more tables. Maybe you should start with a simple MYSQL tutorial or book. https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/offer-listing/0470527587/ref=tmm_pap_used_olp_sr?ie=UTF8&condition=used&qid=&sr=

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have ADDED a password to the `root` userid then by default it comes out of the box without a password.

So just put

```
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
```

Or just leave the password field in phpMyAdmin blank and hit the GO button

**RE: Your comment**: I am using phpMyAdmin

Then the screen should look like this

[image]

Enter `root` in Username and leave the `password:` field empty

Then press the GO button

Comment: if i do that i can even open php admin page

Comment: Have you added a password to the MYSQL `root` user account?

Comment: may i know how to do that

Comment: plz explian me because iam a begineer

Comment: If you have not added a password to the `root` user account then the password is not set to anything. You just **dont enter a password**

Comment: where to set that plz ?

Comment: Please explain: Are you trying to use `phpMyAdmin` or get your PHP script to run????? _PS: phpMyAdmin is not a database_ ___Its a tool written in PHP___ to let you maintain **MYSQL** databases

Comment: iam using phpmyadmin

Comment: i just edited my post and added my prblem screenshot plz checkout

Comment: plz check the image i posted and plz help me, as i already mentioned iam begineer

Comment: **Then you are NOT USING phpMyAdmin** You are querying a MYSQL database, `phpMyAdmin` is a tool written in PHP that lets you create databases and tables and stuff like that

Comment: Then you need to CREATE a database and a table within that database. Maybe you need to ask for some help from someone in your office/school