# What is the risk of `mysql_upgrade` without doing `mysqldump`?

Tags: mysql

After upgradig mysql to 5.7 form 5.5 few months ago, I forgot to do `mysql_upgrade`.

And facing some problems.. `mysql`, `sys`, `performance_schema` databases are missing and root privileges are broken. A lot of `Access denied for user 'root'...` messages pop up, when I try to do some mysql user privileges things.

[This stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8958678/411615) will have to solve my problem. But I need to know it won't affect any of the schemas, data... ect.

Because my database is pretty huge. It amounts to 10 GB and consists of about 50 tables. I'm afraid some bad things could happend. I know the answer will be the `mysqldump`.
But the full backup will cost a long time, maybe an hour. And the business won't accept that downtime.

So what is the risk of `mysql_upgrade` without doing `mysqldump`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The risk of doing *anything* administrative to your database without backups is unacceptably high... not because of any limitations in MySQL *per se*, but because we're talking about something critical to your business.  You should be backing it no less often than the time interval of data you are willing to lose.

If you are using InnoDB, then use the `--single-transaction` option of `mysqldump` and there should be no locking, because MVCC handles the consistency.  If you are not using InnoDB, that is a problem itself, but using `--skip-lock-tables` should mimimize locking.

Note that it *should be quite safe* to kill a `mysqldump` in progress if you find it is causing issues -- find the thread-id of the dump using `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` and then `KILL QUERY #;` where `#` is the ID of the dump connection from the process list.

The potential problem with the answer you cited is that 5.1 > 5.5 is a supported upgrade path, because those two versions are sequential.  5.5 > 5.7 isn't.  You should have upgraded to 5.6 and then 5.7, running *the appropriate versions* of `mysql_upgrade` both before and after each step (appropriate meaning the version of the utility matching the version of the server running at the moment).

You may be in a more delicate situation than you imagine... or you may not.

Given similar circumstances, I would not want to do anything less than stop the server completely, clone it by copying all the files to a new machine, and test the remediation steps against the clone.

If this system is business-critical, it should have a live, running replica server, that could be promoted to master and permanently replace this machine in the event of a failure.  In a circumstance like this one, you would apply your fixes to the replica and promote it.

`Access denied for user 'root'...` may or may not be related to the schema incompatibilites.

Comment: I decided to do a full backup before doing `mysql_upgrade`. Hope everything will be alright.