# mysql showing access denied 1045 even if user has all privilages

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

I am trying to connect to my db using php following is my connection string.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","almawakeb_khawaneej","******");
mysqli_select_db($con, "moodle_amsk_2018");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error(). mysqli_connect_errno().'');
}
else {
die('Connection success');
}
```

But what I am getting is

> Could not connect: Access denied for user
>   'almawakeb_khawaneej'@'localhost' (using password: YES)1045

When I checked privileges for that user

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'almawakeb_khawaneej'@'localhost';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for almawakeb_khawaneej@localhost                                          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'almawakeb_khawaneej'@'localhost'                  |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `moodle_amsk_2018`.* TO 'almawakeb_khawaneej'@'localhost' |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It has all necessary privileges. Password is also correct because it is **working for yii2 framework config file**, that is in the same server.

```
mysql> select version();
+-------------------------+
| version()               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
```

What should be the issue ?

---

**EDIT**

**Resolved !** Actual problem was `$` in the password, you can't use string password in the connection string if it contains `$`. Declare password as a variable.

```
$password = '***$***';
```

Comment: Why doesn't the output show `IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '...'`?

Comment: Can you please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484722/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-while-attempting-to-grant-privileges

Comment: @Barmar all other users in the system don't have that `IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '...'` section even if those users don't have this problem

Comment: Looks like they've taken that out of the output in 5.7. I'm using an older version here.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes... You need to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost as host.

Comment: The error message says that the user is @localhost, so those grants should match it.

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: Ah, yes... Please create the grants for 127.0.0.1 too... If my memory serves me right... 127.0.0.1 forces to use TCP, as localhost will use sockets to connect to MySQL. This is probably causing your issues